# Connect MySQL Database to Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, server

Is this format correct? What am I missing?

I didn't include the correct URLS, I don't want to give it away :P

Comment: and whats the error you are getting?

Comment: phpMyAdmin does nothing actively but rather your Java class connects to a MySQL server where beside other tools is a running phpMyAdmin to administrate the MySQL database. How to connect to a MySQL server through Java is described in a zillion tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am now having trouble with getting the correct address of the URL. It doesn't let me copy paste the URL.I am stuck on this part

Comment: Yes I have looked at those tutorials, but still cannot understand. Any suggestions how I should proceed with this class?

Comment: Can you check my code above?

Comment: What is the problem with it?. PHPmyAdmin is basically a tool - a web application running on localhost. It has nothing to do with what you say.

Comment: @Tiny am a beginner with this, thanks for clarifying that. I am doing as "Smutje" suggested How to connect to a MySQL server through Java. And I am getting this error now

Comment: How do you compile this class? The error message says there is no `main()` method in the `EventSearcher.DBConnect` class. Furthermore, the package name `EventSearcher` does not confirm the general naming convention. It should begin with a small case letter.

Comment: I compiled this class with Eclipse pressing the green Run DBConnect.  public static void main(String args[]) - this is the main method in the class.

The naming convention, I will work on

Comment: @Tinyerror:

java.sql.SQLException: Must specify port after ':' in connection string
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseHostPortPair(NonRegisteringDriver.java:174)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2750)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at DBConnector.main(DBConnector.java:20)

Comment: It is a connection string problem. Specify the MySQL port you are running. It may look like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBName` (the default port is 3306 for MySQL).

Comment: Try this !! This explains well. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Answer (score 0):

But ofc you have to take another programm to realy make your DB phpmyAdmin can't help you there

After you have your DB you need know is the portnumber your Dbname and a User for the Db use it like this :

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:portnumber//dbname";

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
```

Comment: String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:portnumber//dbname";

Localhost? Portnumber? dbname? Im not sure how to obtain these values.

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Not sure what to put in this as my URL is different.

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

By url you mean the actual URL or something else?

Comment: localhost means when the DB is running on the same Computer/Server as your programm. When you start your DB managing program for exampel mysql there is an information like connection xy opened on port 1537 the dbname is the name that your DB has and with url i mean the String mention bevore

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the following and it still doesn't work. I will post my new code above!